# If $f(x)\leq a$ then can we say $\int f(x) dx\leq a\int dx?$

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x)\leq a$ then can we say $$\int f(x) dx\leq a\int dx?$$

I want to know if this is true or not and can we prove the answer. if it's right can you provide a good simple explanation?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Definite or indefinite integrals? Is $f(x)$ integrable?

Comment: What does $a\int\mathrm dx$ mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - I would assume the integral of the empty product, i.e. of $1$

Comment: Basically you’re right. But the integrals should be definite, and we of course must assume that $f$ is integrable. For a simple explanation, think of the integrals as the area under the graph.

Comment: $$f(x)$$ is assumed to be integrable. $$a \int dx$$ means a multiplied by $$b-a$$ assuming that $$b$$ is the upper limit of the integration and $$a$$ is the lower limit of the integration. @JoséCarlosSantos, I cannot understand you, when you assumed as the following "I would assume the integral of the empty product, i.e. of 1".

Comment: @TCHassnaTaha Use `$x$` for inline symbols, *e.g.*, $x$; use `$$x.$$` for emphasis by giving the symbols their own line, *e.g.*, $$x.$$

Comment: Check [the properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities) of defined integral.

Comment: I appreciate your guidance

Comment: but can I also relate and say $$  \lvert f(x)\rvert \leq a$$, then $$ \int_s^d \lvert f(x)\rvert dx \leq a(d-s)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments have noted, this really needs to be discussed with definite integrals, not indefinite ones. Suppose a finite $c$ is chosen so that $\int_c^xf(t)dt$ exists for some finite $x\ge c$. Since$$a\int_c^xdt=\int_c^xadt=a(x-c)$$exists, so does$$a\int_c^xdt-\int_c^xf(t)dt=\int_c^x(a-f(t))dt\ge0,$$where the $\ge$ uses $a-f(t)\ge0$ for all $t\in[c,\,x]$. This rearranges to the expected$$\int_c^xf(t)dt\le a\int_c^xdt=a(x-c).$$

Comment: so how can I explain that this is right theoretically?

Comment: @TCHassnaTaha My argument is all the proof you'll ever need. But unless you're being tested on this particular result, its use can be taken as self-evident in contexts where it's applicable & you'd want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, by integral definition:

$$\int_c^d f(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{d - c}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(c + \frac{(d - c)i}{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} A_n $$

Then

$$ A_n = \frac{d - c}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(c + \frac{(d - c)i}{n}) \le \frac{d - c}{n} \cdot an = a(d - c) $$

Therefore

$$\int_c^d f(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} A_n \le a(d-c) = a\int_c^d dx $$